# Android listing only files with a certain extension via ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent

When displaying a file selection intent via `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, I'd like to get only files with a certain file suffix listed—e.g., only files with `.mysuffix`.

How to do this? Declare some intent filter/MIME type in the manifest?
So I can use that with setType when calling Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT?
If yes for what Intent? Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

My app is not (yet) prepared to be called by others to open such files. It should just be able to open its own data files after user selected the one to open.

Comment: That is not possible when there is no official mime type for it.

Comment: And: ACTION_GET_CONTENT has nothing to do with intent filters in your manifest file.

Comment: Means if it's not an already registered MIME type in the system itself I can only do something like "list all files" with that intent?

Comment: `"image/*"`or `"*/*"` like that.

Comment: Thanks but that would either list all images or all files but not my app specific ones only. Before Android 10/11 things were easy and could be made easy for the user. Now nearly everything is deemed insecure and thus locked up. :-(
And the available solutions only make it harder for users. That's not progress!

Comment: They were only exemples.

Comment: Ok, they were exampleas but as I've read the answers so far I cannot just "add some filter for .mysuffix" so only 1.mysuffix and test.mysuffix are listed even if the same directory contains a 1.txt and a test.jpg and a song.mp3 file...